# Can't get child field font in pdf-lib.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-lib.js

I am trying to get a list of fields and which fonts are assigned to them. I can use `form.getFields()` to get a list of fields in the form. I can then run through the "**dict**" to find the font name - Easy!

[Ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRHGV.png)

However, when I am working with a field that has "**Child Fields**", for example, a pdf with text fields of the same name, it does not have this font parameter.

It only has "**/Kids**" which contains some sort of reference I haven't been able to understand

[Ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TsER.png)

I have also tried this:

```
createPDFAcroFields(fields\[1\].acroField.Kids())
```

However, it returns a blank array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's a jsFidle that grabs the fields and can show you the objects that are missing the font in the console!

https://jsfiddle.net/xek1stmz/13/

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <script>
    const { PDFDocument } = PDFLib

    async function getFieldFonts() {

        // Fetch the PDF with form fields
      const formUrl = 'https://partners.metas.global/Code39.pdf'
      const formPdfBytes = await fetch(formUrl).then(res => res.arrayBuffer())

      // Load a PDF with form fields
      const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes)
      
      // Get the form containing all the fields
      form = pdfDoc.getForm();
      fields = form.getFields();

      console.log(fields);

    }

    getFieldFonts();
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct the body font isUniversLTStd-Light. However , the fields are both set to certain fonts. The first is set to MinionPro-Regular, the next is set to Code39-Regular.

I am aware of the font defaults and I know how to change the fields to the fonts I need in pdf-lib.js, I also can find the fonts for any field easily, however, I cannot find it for fields with the same name. IE: the fields with the name "Barcode" in the file

Comment: Here's another sample file that you can see, I am able to get the font of the first field "Courier Std Bold"

But I am not able to get the fonts of the two fields below it that share the same name:

https://partners.metas.global/Simple%20File.pdf

Comment: Yes, those are the refs and the fonts! How were you able to get them in pdf-lib.js?